# Rendering in batches

Tags: rendering

I am now in a process to finalise a Blender Project. In this project, there are more than 15 nos. of blender files with animations nearly 1500 frames for each of the Blender file.
Now, I need some idea for rendering. Before that let me explain further. As already mentioned, one blender file consists nearly 1500 frames. As per my system strength, 1500 frames can be rendered as .PNG in nearly 4 hours in EVEE and I need a process to render blender files simultaneously one after one, so that rendering of second file can start automatically after finishing of rendering of the first file and so on, without my intervention.

Comment: i would recommend using the free loom add-on. Just search for it on github. It's great, stable and fullfills your needs.

Comment: I have found a tutorial in YouTube but need to check, whether it works for rendering as image. Link:
https://youtu.be/UlpiUOxLKUU

Comment: yeah, of course you can do also everything manually